# How to track registered users with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, user-tracking

We have a website where the users are registered (or not).

We'd like to 'reward' the regular registered visitors.

Well, so what i'd like to do is to check if an user have visited the website on the current day, week, month.. and so on.

Is this possible with Google Analytics?

Comment: If you are using Universal Analytics, you could look in to the new userID feature. Here are some resources: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123668?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660

Comment: Do you mean to reward them in the browsing session or offline?  GA seems like overkill but could technically be used to identify users as long as Google can't identify them.  Since they register on your site, you can either build this into your backend with user registration or store this in cookies.